# Bootrstrap 3 side background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple bootstrap 3 page with a `<div class="container">` for the body.

I would like to put a background image on the page, that best fits around this main container.
I can make images for each "responsive level" of bootstrap.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what it is you're trying to achieve? Do you want the background to go full width or just as wide as the container?

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal image background and design your background images so that graphics of the image follow the container width size (1170px lg container, 970px)...

```
body {
   background: url('link/to/your/image_mobile.jpg') no-repat scroll center top;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
       background: url('link/to/your/image_tablet.jpg') no-repat scroll center top;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
    body {
       background: url('link/to/your/image_small_desktop.jpg') no-repat scroll center top;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
       background: url('link/to/your/image_large_desktop.jpg') no-repat scroll center top;
    }
}
```

Your background image would look somethink like this:

[image]